# Разъезжается форма при использовании хелпера form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

До использования хелпера выглядит вот так
[image: before]
после добавления хелпера разъезжаются поля

[image: after]

Comment: А нужный класс хелперу `form_for` передаете?

Comment: Да, <%= form_for @customer, class: "form-horizontal" do |f| %>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже, просто обратился к старой документации. Вместо

```
<%= form_for @customer, class: "form-horizontal" do |f| %>
```

надо

```
<%= form_for @customer, html: {class: "form-horizontal"} do |f| %>
```